# Xamarin Forms SetBinding with Dictionary of Observable Collections

Tags: xaml, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I have a `listview` that is bound to a `Dictionary` of `Observable Collections` and it works nicely:

```
var Key = "something"; 
myListView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, $"Items[{Key}]");
```

I need to now bind a `Label` to the same source, and use a `Converter` to show visibility if the list is empty, but don't know the format

```
myNoResultsLabel
      .SetBinding(IsVisible??, $"Items[{Key}]"??, Converter=MyEmptyListIsTrueConverter??);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would look something like:

```
myNoResultsLabel.SetBinding(Label.IsVisibleProperty, "NameOfProperty", BindingMode.Default, new MyEmptyListIsTrueConverter());
```

the converter:

```
public class MyEmptyListIsTrueConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((cast)value == value.count > 0)
        {
            return true
        }
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

more info on IValueConverter at [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters) and [example](https://blog.verslu.is/xamarin/xamarin-forms-xamarin/implementing-value-converters-with-ivalueconverter-for-xamarin-forms/)